# Pyusb on Windows 7 cannot find any devices

Tags: python, windows, libusb, pyusb, libusb-1.0

So I installed Pyusb 1.0.0-alpha-1
Under Windows, I cannot get any handles to usb devices.

```
>>> import usb.core
>>> print usb.core.find()
None
```

I do have 1 usb device plugged in(idVendor=0x04d8, idProduct=0x0042), and I tried `usb.core.find(idVendor=0x04d8, idProduct=0x0042)` but that failed too.

Under Ubuntu, with the same versions of pyusb and python (2.6), I am able to successfully find my device with that code, and communicate with it.

So how can I get pyusb to find usb devices on Windows 7?

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but are the drivers installed correctly? It looks like PyUSB has dependencies on libusb. See https://github.com/karlp/karlnet/tree/usbmaster/producers/pyhid/

Comment: @BrianLy That was actually a great question to ask, thanks! I did a little bit of tinkering, and found that the libusb0.1 backend was being loaded instead. It turns out I was using 32bit python and had installed the 64 bit libusb1.0 dll. I replaced that with the 32 bit version, and now usb.core.find() works.

Comment: However, I have other errors now. When I try `device.detach_kernel_header(0)`, I get `USBError: Operation not supported or unimplemented on this platform`.

Comment: Detaching the kernel driver is only implemented on Linux. I guess you are trying to access a HID device, aren't you? I've heard that libusb isn't the best choice then. Try [HIDAPI](http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/) instead but I don't know if there is a python binding available for it.

Answer (score 5):

See [Turbo J's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5767737/1619432). To install the USB driver `libusb` for your device I found two options:

- Use [libusb-win32](http://www.libusb.org/wiki/libusb-win32)'s `inf-wizard.exe` to create the INF file and then use `install-filter-win.exe` to install libusb as driver for your device.
- Use [zadig](http://zadig.akeo.ie/) (simpler)

  - if no device is shown, Options > List All Devices
  - select `libusb-win32` as driver to be installed

Answer (score 4):

Libusb requires you to install a special driver for every device you want to use it with. That usually requires you to write an .inf file containing the USB IDs of the device. Only if the driver and inf file are installed libusb will be able to "see" your device.

Comment: Where does the inf file need to live? I've done as you recommend at am still getting the same result as OP

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same was happening to me in Windows 10 running Python 3.9. According to [the installation instructions of PyUSB](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb#installing) you need to manually install [libusb](https://libusb.info/) on Windows. For this I followed the instructions in the README file shipped with the Windows files (i.e. manually copied `libusb-1.0.dll` and `libusb-1.0.dll.a` into `C:\Windows\System32`) and now PyUSB is listing the devices with

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

list(usb.core.find(find_all=True))
```